# You Tube API Calls

Tags: python, youtube-api

I have cut and pasted a python code sample from Google API to access You Tube video viewing data of my companies videos.  The application will be scheduled and get usage data then write to a database on the server ( CENTOS ).  I have tried both Simple API and installed application types.  Is there a solid samle type that you know of or anyone else having issues with the API calls?  My latest error is that the JSON file is not organized correctly ( which I got from the API page unaltered ).

Answer (score 0):

Most google api code snippet require the user to input their personal API KEY.  Please be sure you have appropriately updated the code snippet to use your api key.